# Prevent modal from closing when error submitting the form (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

So basically I have a bootstrap modal with a form:

#### html:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <!-- some heading here -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-partner">
                    <!-- some form here -->
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align:center;">
                <div id="message"></div>
                <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" id="submit">BUTTON</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And a jQuery script that sends it to *send.php*, where the data is being checked and submitted to the server.

#### js

```
$(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "send.php",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                $("#message").html(msg)
                //$("#modal").modal('hide'); 
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I write an error message to the *div#message*, but I need it to close the modal whenever the submission is successful.

Is there a way to do that, like can I check the data validity (like if email is actually an email) in jQuery *$.ajax* itself?

Comment: So your modal doesn't get hidden if you uncomment that one line? Any validation of data returned from your php can be checked in your success callback

Comment: It closes even if, say, all the fields are empty, or `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` returns _false_. As far as I get, _success:_ in `$.ajax()` corresponds to the successful data send (even if data is invalid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the validation checks before the **$.ajax** call and write error message to the modal if any. Execute ajax only if the validation is successful.

```
$(function() {
$("#submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var email= ....; //get user entered email;
    //validate email (pseudo code)
    if(email is invalid) {
    //display message to div#message
    }
    else {
    //make ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "send.php",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(msg){
            $("#message").html(msg)
            //$("#modal").modal('hide'); 
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
    }
});
});
```

If you're doing the validation on server side, then instead of returning message, you can return codes, like : 1 for success, 2 for bad email, etc.
Then you can do something like this in the ajax function:-

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "send.php",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function(msg){
        if(msg == 1) $("#modal").modal('hide');
        else if(msg == 2) $("#message").html("Bad Email");
        //etc...
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("Failed to submit data");
    }
});
```

If you can post your **send.php** I might be able to give you a complete solution code.

Comment: Well, that worked, of course. I'm submitting data to the server, then `echo`-ing different values and do stuff according to that, like errors, etc. I just thought there might be a more canonic way of solving that.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this using `hide.bs.modal` event. this event fired automatically when modal going to hide

JS

```
$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {        
   // Submit data to server and in success callback write if to validate whether form data is valid or not . 
    if(invalidForm) {           
            e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

and one more simple thing is don't provide any close buttons on modal and use below code. In below code user will not be able to close the modal. user will have only one option to enter data.

JS

```
 $('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
```

or HTML

```
<button data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    Launch demo modal
 </button>
```

`backdrop: static` prevents modal close that occurs through click on screen outside modal.
`keyboard:false` prevents modal close through keyboard. (generally modal can be closed using `ESC` key)

Comment: `backdrop: static` disables hide on click, which is not a good option.

Comment: @HaykHakobyan yes that disables hide on click but its optional, if you want user to force to submit the form then you  can use this

Comment: I already used the answer above, with just sending custom `msg` from .php file and acting according. But, thank you for response!

Comment: But what if I want to give user freedom to close the modal?

Comment: @jaydeepmarvaniya That's a default feature in bootstrap.

Comment: @JSantosh : Thanks, can we bypass this feature somehow?

Comment: @jaydeepmarvaniya whats is your requirement ?

Comment: @JSantosh : Actually I have one form inside Modal, and the form have one zipcode field, whenever this field is invalid zip format, the close buttton and close icon is not working( as you informed, its default feature). but when everything is valid, user is able to close modal and again reopen it with same info. he entered. I want that user still can do the same even if the zip code is invalid.